# Loading movie with a button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to load movies via buttons interaction with ActionScript 3.0. I am creating this movie from Flash CS 5.5.

I could get the first button (I called 'Preface') to work. When adding the second button, I got this error at runtime:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 22  1023: Incompatible override.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 22  1021: Duplicate function definition.
```

There dun seem to be any duplicate that could initiate any overrides:

```
//import flash.events.MouseEvent;

preface.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, preface1);
sq.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sq);

function preface1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Start your custom code
    // This example code displays the words "Mouse clicked" in the Output panel.
    trace("Mouse clicked");

    var preface:Preface= new Preface;
    addChild(preface);
    preface.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, preface1);

    // End your custom code
}

function sq(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //Get sample menus
}
```

Any pointers is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is on line 1023 and 1021?

Comment: `function sq(event:MouseEvent):void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an instance of a MovieClip named `sq`, and you declare a function with name `sq`. This is no longer possible to do with Actionscript 3. You have to name your function something other than `sq` or `preface`, as this name is occupied by your another MC.

Comment: if that is the case, 'preface' wouldn't have worked. Instead, 'Preface' worked fine... Its just 'sq' is giving out the error

Comment: Rename `sq` function, huh?